# If I keep a WeakReference of an activity in AsyncTask, will my application object remain alive?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, weak-references, activity-lifecycle, application-lifecycle

If I keep a `WeakReference` of an activity in `AsyncTask`, will my application object remain alive or will it be garbage collected?

Comment: you can check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309241/warning-this-asynctask-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur. it may help

Comment: There is no clear answer on this part. Let's say I have App A, Activity B, Async C. If Async C has a WeakReference of B, does that keep an Application object in A alive or can that be garbage collected?

Comment: do you know what a WeakReference is?

Comment: @TimCastelijns + more info, the context/timing of operation, in the question is, when an activity has been closed/or closing, however, async is still running, further, it is only a single activity app.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that when you say "my application object" you mean the instance of `android.app.Application` (which may or may not be a subclass depending on your particular `AndroidManifest.xml`).

The `Application` instance for an Android app will never be garbage collected, ever. While your app is running there is a single instance of the `Application` class. The root reference comes from the `ActivityThread` which is the main thread of your app. The `ActivityThread` enters `Looper.loop()` and never returns.

When the Android system decides your app becomes an ["old" cached process](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle) and isn't needed any more then will it be terminated. In that case it doesn't bother letting the `ActivityThread` return so the `Application` instance won't be garbage collected, it will simply be erased when your process stops.

A new `Application` instance will be created the next time Android starts your app.

Thus keeping a `WeakReference` to an `Activity` has no effect on the `Application` instance, as long as your process is running the `Application` instance is available. You may safely keep a reference to the `Application` instance anywhere and access it any time you like, see [Get Application instance from static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337223/get-application-instance-from-static-method) for an example. Alternatively call `Context#getApplicationContext()` and save that for later if needed.